# NetworkStream throws exception on Read() when client shuts down

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I'm having some problems with an app i created. The general situation (the following description is not 1-1 related to question): I have a WCF client-server app for collecting data at multiple sites. The client retrieves local data (some files etc), sends it to the server in the datacenter and this server processes it. The client gets most of its data from the localhost, but some of it is retrieved from different servers on the LAN. Here's where my problem starts. I had to create a 3rd app which sends data to the stated client. In the reminder of this post i refer to client and server as the to apps on the same LAN (so not the server in the datacenter above)

I tried using named pipes, which went superb interprocess on the same host, but was immense slow server-to-server. (if anyone has thoughts on why this is plz dont hesitate to tell me. Some tests went up to 1000 ms sending and receiving just a few bytes)

So i went to using the TcpClient class. Tests showed responses much faster than the NP equivalents, so i decided to go with this option.

Now, when client and server start and end both as they are supposed to do, everything is fine. The problem arrises when the server is fired up, the client has connected, server is waiting its stream.Read() method, and then the client app exits:

`Unable to read data from the transport connection: De externe host heeft een verbinding verbroken.` (2nd part translation: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

At the moment i wrapped the whole part with a Try-Catch statement, restarting the whole thing on a IoException. This does work, but as i read several posts on "An exception should be something exceptional!", it does not feel well.

So finally the question: How can this exception been avoided? 
(What is the normal way to keep a connection between server and client app in real life?)

Server
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

```
        while (true)
        {
            serverSocket.Start();
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);//THIS THROWS THE EXCEPTION WHEN A CLIENT QUITS
                    string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                    string serverResponse = "Server response " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss,fff");
                    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);

                    int len = sendBytes.Length;
                    networkStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
                    networkStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));

                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    break;
                }

            }
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
        }
    }
```

client

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message from Client$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();
        int len = serverStream.ReadByte() * 256;
        len += serverStream.ReadByte();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[len];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, len);
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        msg("Data from Server : " + returndata);
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when one party disconnects forcefully? I think an exception is normal for that situation. Maybe you should modify both parties to not force the connection closed.

Comment: Not entirely related to the question you're asking, but just because you're doing a `Read` of a particular number of bytes, doesn't mean that that is how many bytes that will be read by the call, you need to check the return value, and if necessary, call `Read` again until you have received the number of bytes expected.

Comment: @usr, ok thanks, but what is the normal way to handle situations like this? Meaning: the idea is the apps communicate 24-7, during working hours multiple times per minute, at night possibly no traffic at all. Should I close down the connection after each send, or just accept the exceptions on a network failure etc, and restart it then? Or can the client notify the server it will shut down, when the server is waiting on Read()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the `Socket` API is that you are supposed to call `Shutdown(Write)` when you are done sending. Then, read until the stream returns 0. This means that the other side has called `Shutdown`, too.

Only after you have closed writing (using `Shutdown`) and received a zero-length read, the communication is really done on the wire. Now `Dispose` the `Socket` as it is now defunct.

That way you only get an exception if a network error or a bug occurred. In that case you should probably discard the current "transaction" and restart it.

Comment: Thanks! This made it exit the Read() method nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This error has several causes, butt the most common is that you wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error: you wrote something in a situation where it could never be consumed.

Another somewhat remote possibility if you wrote both ends is that you coded the client to close abortively for some reason. Basically you should never do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, i do know WHY the exception gets trown (indeed when the client shuts down forcefully, like you said), but my problem is: how to avoid it? Did i took the right solution by keeping the connection open and the server waiting on Read()? Or is the normal situation to close after each send? Can the server be notified by a closing client when the server is waiting for the stream? I read multiple samples on how to communicate, but none addressing the issue of what to do to keep a connection alive real life (meaning client computer can shut down, network issues, etc)